# How do I display 9 equal divs in a row using bootstrap css

Tags: html, row

Something like this, using bootstrap css class

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <h1>FK8.IR</h1>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md" style="background-color:#eee;">FK8</div>
                <div class="col-md" style="background-color:#ccc;">FK8</div>
                <div class="col-md" style="background-color:#eee;">FK8</div>
                <div class="col-md" style="background-color:#eee;">FK8</div>
                <div class="col-md" style="background-color:#ccc;">FK8</div>
                <div class="col-md" style="background-color:#eee;">FK8</div>
                <div class="col-md" style="background-color:#eee;">FK8</div>
                <div class="col-md" style="background-color:#ccc;">FK8</div>
                <div class="col-md" style="background-color:#eee;">FK8</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```